# Form tag closing automatically

Tags: jquery, html, css, netsuite

I have an issue where a form tag is automatically closed.

I'm trying to  figure out what exactly is causing the problem. Whatever is inside of the form tag is added after. I'm using netsuite thats why the items are in tables and it is also a little harder to debug. Here is the link to the site. 
   T

This is (partly) what is generated on the browser

```
>   <div class="col-xs-8"> 
>      <div class="oos-button"></div> 
>         <form method="get" id="add-to-cart-form" role="form" action="/app/site/backend/additemtocart.nl"></form>


 <!-- MODAL -->   etc...
```

But the modal code should  go inside the form and that's how i have coded it.

```
<form method="get" id="add-to-cart-form" role="form" action="/app/site/backend/additemtocart.nl">

 <!-- MODAL -->          
  <div id="<%=getCurrentAttribute('item','itemID')%>" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
  <div class="modal-dialog">
     <div class="modal-content" style="padding:15px 15px; " >
       <h2 class="page-title serif text-center "><@= meal.storedisplayname @></h2>
         <div id="product-image" class="img-rounded">
           <img src="<@=meal.storedisplaythumbnail  @>" class="img-responsive center" alt="">
            <br />
          <p><strong> <@= meal.storedisplayname @></strong>:  added to cart</p>
 <label style="color:#7b9738"> Price: $<@= meal.onlineprice @></label>
    <hr / > 
       <hr / > 
           <div class="text-center">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-info center" data-dismiss="modal">Continue Shopping</button>
           <a  href="<%=getCartUrl()%>">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-info center">Checkout ></button>
           </a>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
              <!-- END MODAL-->
                              <%= getCurrentAttribute('item','addtocartitemid')%>
                            <input type="text" class="qty form-control" name="qty" placeholder="Qty" value="1" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="showcart" value="T" />
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Add to Cart</button>
                      </form>
```

Comment: You have several forms nested inside a form. That is not valid HTML, and it will end up in an unexpected behavior depending on the browser (from past experience, although things may have changed). Your problem may be solved by fixing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some browsers need the `<form>` object to open and close within the same parent. In your case, you open a form within a `<tr>` and then close it within an adjacent `<tr>`. If you correct that form, it might fix your other problem.

Not sure where in your source files, but lines #242-257 of the generated output at the URL you sent.

```
<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width='100%'>
<tr class='portletHandle' id='handle_itemMainPortlet' >
<td width='100%' height=0 align='left' valign='top'>
<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width='100%'>
<tr>
<td width=0 height=0 align='left' valign='top' style='display:none'>
<form method='post' name='form0' id='form0' action='/s.nl'>
<input type='hidden' name='c' value='3374347'>
<input type='hidden' name='n' value='1'>
<input type='hidden' name='sc' value='39'>
<input type='hidden' name='category' value='13945'>
<input type='hidden' name='id' value=''>
<input type='hidden' name='it' value='A'>
<input type='hidden' name='vid' value='RHCpZYbgAWoCAF5X'>
<input type='hidden' name='ck' value='RHCpZYbgAVkCAEOd'>
<input type='hidden' name='cktime' value='123014'>
<input type='hidden' name='cart' value='-1'>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
</form>
```

Should rather be:

```
<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width='100%'>
<tr class='portletHandle' id='handle_itemMainPortlet' >
<td width='100%' height=0 align='left' valign='top'>
<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width='100%'>
<tr>
<td width=0 height=0 align='left' valign='top' style='display:none'>
<form method='post' name='form0' id='form0' action='/s.nl'>
<input type='hidden' name='c' value='3374347'>
<input type='hidden' name='n' value='1'>
<input type='hidden' name='sc' value='39'>
<input type='hidden' name='category' value='13945'>
<input type='hidden' name='id' value=''>
<input type='hidden' name='it' value='A'>
<input type='hidden' name='vid' value='RHCpZYbgAWoCAF5X'>
<input type='hidden' name='ck' value='RHCpZYbgAVkCAEOd'>
<input type='hidden' name='cktime' value='123014'>
<input type='hidden' name='cart' value='-1'>
<!-- Move here: --></form>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

Comment: Netsuite adds that code to the page automatically i'm not able to edit that.

Comment: Sounds like you need to get in touch with Netsuite... sorry!

Comment: I feel like this answer led me down the correct path I had to wrap a  td tag to the container div. td tags are mandatory in netsuite inner cell templates.. its something I unfortunately have to work with.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When I look at your source code for the page link you provided, I see no closing tag on the same line for that form (line 293, ...) as you state in your first snippet. It would be strange too, cause it would mean you are adding an empty form. I think the problem is on the server side here...

I also noticed you are using that same form id (add-to-cart-form) 9 times on your page, which is invalid HTML as id's should always be unique. You probably want to go with a class are some `data-` attribute here, or your javascript is bound to fail sooner or later.

Comment: What do you mean serverside? Could you please elaborate I was thinking the same thing but i hit a road block.

Comment: I can only tell you what I can see in the browser, and that is clearly not what you are expecting. In other words, the generated HTML is incorrect, so you will have to fix where it is being generated, on the server.